# Dynamic body is null in Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection, collision

I have one dynamic sprite and few static. My dynamic body:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

bodyDef.position.set(180, 20);
bodyMonkey = world.createBody(bodyDef);
PolygonShape abcBox = new PolygonShape(); 
bodyMonkey.setUserData(monkey1);
bodyMonkey.setFixedRotation(true);
abcBox.setAsBox(10.0f, 10.0f);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = abcBox;
fixtureDef.density = 0.5f; 
fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.9f; 
Fixture fixture = bodyMonkey.createFixture(fixtureDef);
abcBox.dispose();
bodyMonkey.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(1f, 0.5f));
bodyMonkey.setLinearDamping(1.0f);
```

I have to implement ContactListener. My class:

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Object a =  contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    Object b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();// null

    Gdx.app.log("1", ""+a);
    Gdx.app.log("2", ""+b);
    if(a!=null&&b!=null) {
        Gdx.app.log("ok", "");
        screen2dBox.restartGame();
    }
}

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

But object b is alaways null (a no, b is dynamic, I saw it in my logs). I have try to use try, catch, finally to overcome this (in finally block - screen2dBox.restartGame();) but I had error that contact can not be null. I don't know how does it solve? thanks for help.

static body:

```
BodyDef bodyDefPlatform1 = new BodyDef();
     bodyDefPlatform1.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
     bodyDefPlatform1.position.set(50, 280);
     bodyPlatform1 = world.createBody(bodyDefPlatform1 );
     PolygonShape platformBox1 = new PolygonShape();  
     bodyPlatform1.setUserData(platform);
     platformBox1.setAsBox(20.0f, 10.0f);
     FixtureDef fixtureDefPlatform1 = new FixtureDef();
     fixtureDefPlatform1.shape = platformBox1;
     Fixture fixturePlatform = bodyPlatform1.createFixture( fixtureDefPlatform1);
    platformBox1.dispose();
```

Comment: Can you post initialization code of any of the static bodies?

Answer (score 0):

I check your code, I can't see any error. Maybe the object monkey1 is null.

```
bodyMonkey.setUserData(monkey1); //check if monkey1 is null.
```

Note: I have low reputacion, I can't post this as comment.